# Term for a joke with a missing punchline

Tags: humor, jokes, puns

What do you call a joke that has a punchline which as been emphatically implied *through omission*,  as in...

> [Comedian peeling banana, saying...]
>
> "one skin, two skin, three skin, (pregnant pause)...five skin"

[...arch look and lifted eyebrows]

Benny Hill used to do a lot of this, and I am trying find a name for it.
I have looked up [types and classes of jokes](https://www.masterclass.com/articles/the-10-most-popular-types-of-jokes#10-most-popular-types-of-jokes), but cannot find a definition for it.

Comment: I would call it "pulling your punches".

Comment: @HotLicks That is interesting. I have heard the phrase but only in the reference of not hitting someone too hard...

Comment: In the case of Benny Hill, I'd call it censory deprivation.

Comment: I am sorry @KJ, I just now realized that you had answered the Q in comment. It was perfect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Mobitela Fonia's  answer, and (now it seems) to K J's comment, I was able to track down a definition at the same source which pretty much gave the best answer.

***Stealth pun***

> The writers put in a joke (almost always a pun), but never make or put in a Punch Line or explicit statement, hiding it in the set up of the joke. Some percentage of the audience will "get" the joke, but the rest will know it was there and be going, "What? Why didn't you say it?" There can be several reasons.
>
> 1) It's naughty or otherwise not appropriate for this timeslot, in which case this serves the same purpose as a Last-Second Word Swap.

[-TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StealthPun)

Answer (score 1):

I should imagine it would have to be something which, as with all jokes, creates an expectation, which it then disappoints, but perhaps not without a *double entendre*.  How about this?

> Iocus interruptus

Comment: As Mel Brooks once said, "It's all a ...matter of..........................timing."

Comment: While sex is often comedic, and comedy sometimes sexual, I could only read that with the implication of your _double entendre_...cool. +1

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

**shaggy-dog story**

> A long, drawn-out anecdote ending with an absurd or anticlimactic punch line.

Comment: Sorry, but "anticlimactic punch line" does not address the main point of the question, which asks for a _missing_ punchline.

Comment: Yeah, didn't read the question properly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: No problem...I actually love shaggy dog stories. Issac Asimov, along with my grandfather, were masters of that arcane  "art".

Comment: Asimov I know. Have read him after a fashion. Interested to know more about your grandfather. Was he a writer too?

Comment: My grandfather (only a voracious reader, not a writer)  introduced me to Asimov's stories in the 60s. Later, in the early 80s,  I met Asimov and did an interview for our regional newspaper. Incredibly intelligent man. A deep thinker.

Comment: @Cascabel— Holy smoke! You interviewed Asimov? That's quite an achievement in itself. _Applause_ mate. I feel smart to be talking with you! ;) You happen to have a recording of that interview? I have seen one of his interviews (he was on the Dick Cavett show probably and I liked it very much.)

Comment: Sorry, but no...it was back in the days of tape, and that media does not do well  for 40 years. I have only my memories...

Comment: I see. It feels great to be in touch with people like yourself! :) Thanks to ELU. Just this last thing before we are "sued" for protracting the chat here— What, retrospectively, was the most intelligent question that you asked him and how did he respond? (If you don't mind sharing.)

Comment: I asked him what he was most worried about in the near future. He was extremely concerned about the Reagan "Space Defense  Initiative" whatever , which supposedly put killer satellites in orbit in the early 80s. He was worried that it would create an imbalance of power between the USSR and the USA. He was quite passionate on the idea. Now, we have the US Space Force...and the same concerns. He also alluded to another impending danger, which later I interpreted to be a biological issue. I did not press him on the issue. My bad.

Comment: A brilliant mind! Thank you, @Cascabel. Made my day! :)

Comment: Thank you,  for taking me back in time...It made me think that in those days, we did not have a definitive test   for AIDS. Ebola and SARS were on the far horizon. Pandemic was a word in the dictionary. I'm gonna see if there were any Asimov stories that predicted this. +1 for the time-travel.

Answer (score 0):

According to "TV-Tropes" a joke without a punchline is an "orphaned setup" (the information was obtained from: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OrphanedSetup).

> When characters tell jokes, the whole joke is rarely told. We hear either the punchline or setup. In this case, only the setup.

So in this case there is no real punchline, and is "orphaned".

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OrphanedSetup

Comment: What I am saying is please include it your question? Just click on the [EDIT] button.

Comment: Sorry, but "shaggy dog" stories totally depend on the punchline.

Comment: I am starting to reconstruct your answer. If you are not happy with the changes I make you can "roll-back".

Comment: This is not what is being asked for in my opinion.  In the OP the punchline is there it’s just not verbal.   I think of the orphaned setup as what happens in Breakfast Club when the joke is interrupted by Bender falling through the ceiling.

Answer (score 0):

Also, another way of naming a joke of this sort is a "mind joke" a bit like a "mind rhyme" (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_rhyme).
But, as far as I have seen, an official name for this joke-form does not exist.

Comment: Hi Mobitela...could you please edit your original post? I liked it, and it would greatly benefit from a few edits, including the info in this answer.

Answer (score -2):

I do not know if there exists some unique type of humor for it. But I think that there are a few types of humor that could support the kind we are discussing here.
Right now the ones that come to my mind are: Wit and Wordplay.

Comment: This is a low-quality answer. The "I don't know, I think, me, we, my"  sentences show an opinion.

Comment: Well, yes, id couldn't answer the question so yes we can say that was just an opinion. Anyway, I saw this blog while searching for this type of humor and it had 45 different types. I don't think that this one quite matches any of those descriptions, but have a look if you think it lies in any of these: https://humornama.com/featured/education/types-of-humor/

Comment: I self-answered over a year ago...and it seems to be the right one given the criteria i.e.Stealth pun.